# Is there a Windows IDE that can handle both C and Perl?

Tags: c, windows, perl, svn, ide

I'm using Strawberry Perl which includes MinGW's GCC, I'm also making use of the GNU debugger GDB and Subversion. How can I have a single development environment that would suit this (other than just UltraEdit, the command shell and IE), and how can I further enhance its features?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd have a good look at [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) if I were you! Then have a look at the [EPIC](http://www.epic-ide.org/) IDE Plug-in.

Subversion integrates quite nicely with that IDE via [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) or even better as mentioned in one of the comments by Davide Gualano, [Subversive](http://www.polarion.org/index.php?page=overview&project=subversive).

Comment: A better way to integrate Eclipse with SVN is by usinge  the Subversive plugin: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/

Comment: Yes! Well put. I think I had a brain cramp and was thinking of using Tortoise for VS and our Progress development. We use subversive for our eclipse integration.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse is a really good IDE
The Target Management plugin (http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/) is also really cool to work on remote projects/files

Comment: I've never used Subversive, but we use Subclipse where I work: http://subclipse.tigris.org/

Comment: I used eclipse for JAVA in the past and liked it a lot, but when I tried to install a fresh eclipse for perl on a different PC, it gave me a bunch of errors and I gave up.

Answer (score 7):

Personally i'm using Komodo IDE from ActiveState. Komodo Edit might suit your needs and is its free alternative.

Answer (score 6):

You can use emacs for windows.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/ntemacs.html

Comment: I can recommend http://www.ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html. It is customized for windows.

Answer (score 4):

msvc 6 will do the job quite nicely.

my perl is installed at c:\perl\bin so...

under the custom menu, create a new tool.

command **c:\perl\bin\perl.exe** 

arguments  **-w $(FileName)$(FileExt)**

initial directory **$(FileDir)**

check the Use Output Window.

create a button on your tool bar, to run the tool.
The perl output will come out in the output window.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried Notepad++?  It's mostly an "all stops pulled out" text editor with code highlighting for every language you can think of.  But, it does have a pretty amazing macro / external command / extension thing, so hooking it up to a compiler is pretty easy.

I'm currently using it for C, Inform, Python, Perl, HTML, and VB.Net, with surprisingly few issues when shifting gears.

Also, FOSS.

(and, I've just discovered that it has code completion as well.  Excellent!)

Answer (score 3):

I'm no Windows developer or IDE user by a long shot, but the combination of Cygwin (for all the handy Unix tools and a better shell) and emacs does the job when I have to work on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm happily using [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) for C, C++, Perl and Python development on Windows. Using a single tool has a lot of advantages for me - as becoming expert in it improves my productivity in all languages. SciTE has a built-in scripting language, and is also quite easy to combine it with external scripting, so it's extensible beyond imagination - and that using quite standard tools.

Comment: SciTE would be a good solution except that apparently it doesn't do regular expressions which span lines.

Comment: What do you mean by "do regular expressions" ? In what context ?

Comment: How to do a multiline replace e.g. all foo\nbar (foo on one line bar on the next line) with bar\nbaz? The faq at http://pgl.yoyo.org/scite/docs/SciTEFAQ.html#NewlineInRegEx seems to say it can't be done.

Comment: I don't know if any IDE does a multiline recursive replace, even most plain text editors don't seem to offer this.