# On Windows is there a **light-weight** IDE that can be used both with C and Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, svn, ide, gnu-toolchain

When I asked this [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266121/is-there-a-windows-ide-that-can-handle-both-c-and-perl) I should have mentioned that it's particularly a **light-weight** IDE that I'm after, so I’m having to ask again as a different question.

Something that is not just a text editor, is light-weight and versatile, that would suit Strawberry Perl, the GCC that comes with MinGW, GDB and Subversion. Something that when I want to use it is straight-away available, and is also fast to shut down preserving all my work. It doesn't matter if it's not a free or open-source program, what does matter is that it’s stable and is comfortable to use.

Maybe trying to have one IDE to use for both C and Perl is the wrong way to go about it - resulting in a solution that's not going to handle either one language or the other as well as a dedicated IDE would?

Comment: You pretty much answered your question in the last sentence. If it's going to support both languages, it's probably going to support a lot many others too, and hence will probably have the resulting heavyweight baggage. I'd be (perhaps pleasantly) surprised to see a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided to use the open source and cross platform [Codelite](http://codelite.org/Main/ReadMore) IDE, with C/C++, it's just about as light-weight as I'm going to get without using a plain text editor.

It can use either VC++,  GCC, G++ or it can be configured to use other compilers if required.  It does more than a text editor, which is what I'll carry on using for Perl until I find something better. Unfortunately for Perl currently it only offers syntax highlighting, so no real incentive to use it here instead of some text editor or Padre.

Although still relatively new (v1.0 released July 1st 2008) Codelite is already a better IDE than Dev C++ or Code::Blocks and not as slow or bloated as Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

[Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) is a language neutral IDE that can be be configured for almost any programming langauge.

It has features like syntax highlighting, code folding, project/workspace management, class browsing, macro scripting, integrated version control, ftp editing etc.

[image]
<sub>(source: [zeusedit.com](http://www.zeusedit.com/images/_lookmain.jpg))</sub>

Comment: For that price, I'd rather use NotePad

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/), the Perl Application Development and Refactoring Environment?

It's still in development so you can help make it better.

Answer (score 2):

[SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) would be worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) is another [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/)-based (as [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html)) source code editor.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Geany for gnome. It's relatively new, but interesting. And it seems to be lightweight.

http://www.geany.org/

Comment: Geany is multiplatform, not just Gnome (important for the OP, who is on Windows).  It does use GTK, though.  There is a Windows installer which has the necessary runtime bundled in.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.

Notepad.

(I can feel my Rep draining away as I type this)

:-)

Comment: make it Notepad++ and it won't be sarcasm!

Comment: We bad jokers should stick together. +1

Comment: Notepad is not an IDE, how is this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Eclipse? I don't know if it's light weight enough for you but out of all the decent IDES I've used it's the fastest one in my experience. You should  be able to download the standard eclipse distribution, then install the c++ and Perl tools. The C++ tools can be installed through the update manager from the Ganymede site that's included by default. Information about Perl for Eclipse can be found at this link.
http://www.epic-ide.org/

Comment: Eclipse is not lightweight. In fact, it is one of the worst memory hogs I have seen.

Comment: Right. The OP has probably already tried Eclipse. And then came here to ask for something that is not as heavy.

Answer (score 0):

[E Text Editor](http://e-texteditor.com/) is a TextMate analog for Windows. It is not free.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at jEdit.

Answer (score 0):

Dev-C++ very nice IDE.
http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the most light-weight of the bunch, but [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/Products/komodo_ide/komodo_edit.mhtml)  seems to be a good compromise between features and program size.  It supports many languages and is pretty flexible.

Answer (score -2):

The lightest-weight open-source text-editor that I'd consider a full IDE is [SharpDevelop](http://icsharpcode.com/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx), which is still a bit heavy-weight. It handles a number of different languages, although I'm not should if it does anything specific for Perl.

Comment: It doesn't support C/C++ or Perl.